# scrape article from a website that requires credential with scrapy

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to scrape article from a website that requires a credential. I try to follow the instruction from https://python.gotrained.com/scrapy-formrequest-logging-in/

and my final code is below

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class petromindonews(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'petromindonews'
    start_urls = ['https://petromindo.com/login']
    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath('//*[@name ="csrf_token"]/@content').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata ={'csrf_token': token,
                                                    'password': 'foobar',
                                                    'email': 'foobar'},
                                         callback=self.scrape_pages)
    def scrape_pages(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)


    def parse_link(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//*[@class="col-12   col-md-6  "]/article/div/a/@href'):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link.get(),
                callback=self.parse_item
            )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'date': response.xpath('//*[@class="article-meta"]/span/text()').re(r'\w+?\s\d\d,\s\d{4}'),
            'category': 'oil & gas',
            'title': response.xpath('//*[@class="article-title"]/text()').get(),
            'text':''.join([x.get().strip() for x in response.xpath('//*[@class="article-content use-sans-serif"]//p//text()')])
            }
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(petromindonews)
    process.start()
```

when I run the code, I did not find any error but the script did not get into the website and scrape the articles. The log I got when I run the code is below:

```
2022-08-01 15:03:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2022-08-01 15:03:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.3.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.4.0, Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 12:59:45) - [Clang 10.0.0 ], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021), cryptography 3.4.7, Platform macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit
2022-08-01 15:03:44 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{}
2022-08-01 15:03:44 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2022-08-01 15:03:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: e62bdc3ee25b0a45
2022-08-01 15:03:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-08-01 15:03:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-08-01 15:03:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-08-01 15:03:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-08-01 15:03:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-08-01 15:03:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-08-01 15:03:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2022-08-01 15:04:19 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 140287248782336 on /Users/user/.cache/python-tldextract/3.8.8.final__anaconda3__ff1e9e__tldextract-3.3.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-08-01 15:04:19 [filelock] INFO: Lock 140287248782336 acquired on /Users/user/.cache/python-tldextract/3.8.8.final__anaconda3__ff1e9e__tldextract-3.3.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-08-01 15:04:19 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 140287248782336 on /Users/user/.cache/python-tldextract/3.8.8.final__anaconda3__ff1e9e__tldextract-3.3.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-08-01 15:04:19 [filelock] INFO: Lock 140287248782336 released on /Users/user/.cache/python-tldextract/3.8.8.final__anaconda3__ff1e9e__tldextract-3.3.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-08-01 15:04:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://petromindo.com/login> (referer: None)
2022-08-01 15:04:20 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET https://petromindo.com> from <POST https://petromindo.com/login>
2022-08-01 15:04:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://petromindo.com> (referer: https://petromindo.com/login)
2022-08-01 15:04:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-08-01 15:04:21 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2420,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 22046,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 36.629223,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 1, 8, 4, 21, 550815),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 138946,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/INFO': 12,
 'memusage/max': 79290368,
 'memusage/startup': 79290368,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 1, 8, 3, 44, 921592)}
2022-08-01 15:04:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

How can I get scrape the articles from the website?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a typo in your `parse` method.  Its `FormRequest.from_response`  not `FormRequest.form_response`

Comment: Thanks! I have fixed the typo, and now the code can go to the login page. However, it's unsuccessfully to login into the page. How should I fix that? @Alexander

Comment: Please update your question with what the output looks like now, and what your code looks like now

Comment: I have updated my question, please take a look. Thank you @Alexander